# Update firebase user information is not working properly

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I am trying to update firebase user information, but it is not working properly where I need to hot restart the app to see the changes. This is the method that I am using

```
Future<void> saveUserNumber(
      {String number, PhoneAuthCredential phoneCredential}) async {
    try {

      await user.updatePhoneNumber(phoneCredential);
      await Get.find<FirestoreService>().saveUserPhoneNumber(user.uid, number);
      print('user before reload $user');
      await user.reload();
      
      update();
      print('user after reload $user'); //prints null phone number
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.message);
    }
  }
```

note that signing out works fine but I am not sure why this is not working as well as when I try to change the display name.

and this is what I am using to listen to the user changes with Getx package

```
// get firebase user, make it observable
  Rx<User> _firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.obs;
  // getter for user
  User get user => _firebaseUser.value;

 @override
  void onInit() {
    super.onInit();
    _firebaseUser.bindStream(_auth.authStateChanges());
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved!

```
@override
  void onInit() {
    super.onInit();
    // _firebaseUser.bindStream(_auth.authStateChanges());
    _firebaseUser.bindStream(_auth.userChanges());
  }
```

the reason why it was not working is that authStateChanges() listens to the authentication status of the user and doesn't listen to other things such as credentials.

the solution is to use userChanges() instead of authStateChanges() where the userChanges() method has the functionality of listening to the auth state as well as the credentails